# how do you use the google review Gatsby plugin?

Tags: plugins, gatsby, google-reviews

I'm trying to use the gatsby-source-google-reviews plugin. Upon trying to run develop, I get an invalid API key message. Where do I find and put this API key? And is the API key considered the same thing as the placeID?

Comment: ok, i figured that part out. I had to add the apikey option, along with an apikey from ScaleSerp.com, to the plugin in the gatsby-config file. Now I'm not too sure how to shape the Graphql query. I pulled the query shape from Graphiql but I keep getting a 'Cannot query field "googleReview" on type "Query".' error. Anyone know where I can find an example of this plugin in use?

Comment: Did you try the example GraphQL query here?  
 https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-source-google-reviews/

Comment: @ksav i did try that. I also tried. `query {
    googleReview {
      internal {
        content
      }
      rating
      source
    }
  }`  i pulled from the graphiql.

Comment: I ended up successfully using the google-place plugin instead.